# Python module pyautogui doesn't work properly. OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I need to open Telegram.app and using `pyautogui` method, find a contact using a screenshot, and then write to him. Telegram was opened and the image requirable was seen there. But python has sent the mouse under the dock panel on OS X. Why? Screenshot is located properly, it's inside the directory where code is launched. How can I use this method successfully?

```
import os
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
os.system('open /Applications/Telegram.app')
contact = os.path.abspath('contact.png')
sleep(3)
to_click = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(contact)
pyautogui.click(to_click)
```

Comment: I believe `locateCenterOnScreen()` returns a tuple of x,y coordinates, and you're supposed to pass those coordinates separately to the `click()` function.

Comment: Hmmm, I’ll try it when I’ll be at home. But I think there’s something else that I should change.